# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' - Dll being removed on build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite, monodevelop

I am trying to include SQLite in a project. It compiles, but when I try and call a method that references SQLite from another project (a class library with unit tests) I get an "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'" error.

Looking in my bin/Debug folder I found that the x64 and x86 folders were empty. I copied SQLite.Interop.dll from another project that is working to those folders and rebuilt. I included the files in my projects and set them to "Copy Always."
During the build the files were deleted and the build failed because "Could not copy the file "\\bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" because it was not found."

I am using Visual Studio 2015 but I also work on this project in Mono Develop and I am targeting .NET 4.5.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually dlls are not copied when no classes are explicitly used from them. If you want to copy the dll even though no classes are referenced, then click on the reference in the project and open properties (e.g. by hitting F4). You will find an item which says "Copy Local". Set this to true, and the dll will be copied to the bin folder.

Comment: Setting to copy local didn't work, but the root cause you described is very plausible. My project that consumes the SQLite project is a code generator, so the compiler would have no way of seeing the code that actually uses SQLite.
Creating x64 and x86 folders at the project level and putting the dlls in those folders has gotten rid of the issue but I don't know why.